# Image not coming properly in pdf DomPDF

Tags: ckeditor, dompdf

I have project in which user make content using ck editor after that pdf is made using dompdf. But the problem occur when some select some area and do actions like bold, italic and changing font then these changes also applied to the images. then images in pdf not properly shown.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/131Ru.png)

I tried all the solution which came to my mind. But Didn't work for me.